# Unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable - setting permissions unsuccessful

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions

I've tried everything on the first 3 of 4 pages of Google plus everything else on server fault and nothing has worked, the error I get is as follows:

```
[crit] [client] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/html/multicraft/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

I've tried `chmod 755` on `/var/www/html/multicraft` and recursively but nothing, no luck at all. Be aware that I do have SELinux installed on the server but that has never caused issues with this install before.

Here's the permissions for `/var/www/html`, output of `ls -l`:

```
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root     20 Aug  5 15:07 info.php
drwxr-xr-x. 8 apache apache 4096 Aug  5 15:08 multicraft
```

And the output of `/var/www/html/multicraft`:

```
total 40
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  560 Nov  9  2012 api.php
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache 4096 Nov  9  2012 assets
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache 4096 Nov  9  2012 css
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache 2550 Nov  9  2012 favicon.ico
drwxr-xr-x.  7 apache apache 4096 Nov  9  2012 images
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  660 Nov  9  2012 index.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  620 Nov  9  2012 install.php
drwxr-xr-x.  5 apache apache 4096 Nov  9  2012 net2ftp
drwxr-xr-x. 12 apache apache 4096 Nov  9  2012 protected
drwxr-xr-x.  5 apache apache 4096 Nov  9  2012 themes
```

And for `/var/www/html/multicraft/.htaccess`:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 451 Nov 9 2012 .htaccess
```

---

And finally the output of `ls -lad / /var /var/www /var/www/html /var/www/html/multicraft`:

```
dr-xr-xr-x. 22 root   root   4096 Aug  5 13:59 /
drwxrwxr-x. 21 root   root   4096 Aug  5 14:00 /var
drwxrwxr-x.  6 root   root   4096 Aug  5 13:21 /var/www
drwxrwxr-x.  3 apache apache 4096 Aug  5 15:08 /var/www/html
drwxrwxr-x.  8 apache apache 4096 Aug  5 15:08 /var/www/html/multicraft
```

Comment: Could you show output of the # ls -lad / /var /var/www /var/www/html /var/www/html/multicraft (please add the output to the question)

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: is there any messages in the /var/log/audit/audit.log? Also you could try do the trick su - apache --shell=/bin/bash & cat /var/www/html/multicraft/.htaccess

Comment: @ALex_hha This is repeated a few times in the audit log file: http://pastebin.com/criBu038.

Comment: @ALex_hha And that command correctly prints out the contents of the .htaccess file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1375733894.906:43363): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=11191 comm="httpd" 
"name=".htaccess" dev=dm-0 ino=2624761 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0`
tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 tclass=file
```

As I see from the output it seems that problem in selinux. You could temporally disable it and try again. Also you could try to get current context

```
# ls --context /var/www/html/multicraft/.htaccess
```

Comment: How might I disable it? The current context is: `-rw-r--r--. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 /var/www/html/multicraft/.htaccess`

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to disable it with `echo 0 >/selinux/enforce` and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the issue, it is better to [`restorecon -Rvf /var/www/html/`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/restorecon)

I think it's not a good idea to disable SELinux, it can prevent many exploits and privilege escalations.